# Elasticsearch - match_phrase on items with hyphen fail

Tags: php, elasticsearch

In my program, the user can "disable" fuzzy searching on the front-end. This changes the back-end request to the following:

```
$query['query']['bool']['must'][] = [
    'bool' => [
        'should' => [
            ['match_phrase' => ['name' => $param]],
            ['match_phrase' => ['description' => $param]],
        ],
        'minimum_should_match' => 1,
    ],
];
```

The `$param` is the search query. The document I am looking to hit is `Evo-Singularity`.

The following is my hits on this:

`evo` => works

`evo-` => works

`evo-sing` => no results

`singularity` => works

With that in mind, I've tried changing to a `wildcard` approach:

```
$param = '*'.$param.'*';
//No Fuzzy Search - Do a literal match
$query['query']['bool']['must'][] = [
    'wildcard' => [
         'name' => $param
    ],
    'wildcard' => [
         'description' => $param
    ],                
];
```

`evo` => works

`evo-` => no results

`evo-sing` => no results

`singularity` => no results

Then I went to the console to try see if I could find it:

This works:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "evo-singularity"
    }
  }
}
```

None of these wildcard searches work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name": {
        "value": "*evo\\-singularity*",
        "boost": 1.0,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name": {
        "value": "*evo*singularity*",
        "boost": 1.0,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this does work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name": {
        "value": "*singularity*",
        "boost": 1.0,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the actual document in elasticsearch. I've removed all unnecessary information:

```
"_source": {
          "type": "Trap Card",
          "description": "Target 1 \"Evoltile\" monster and 1 \"Evolsaur\" monster in your Graveyard; Special Summon 1 \"Evolzar\" Xyz Monster from your Extra Deck, and if you do, attach those monsters to it as Xyz Materials.",
          "name": "Evo-Singularity",
        },
```

At this stage, I'm out of ideas. Documents that have space hyphen space seem to work without issue:

```
vanquish soul - kaiser
```

But documents that have no space around the hyphens have issue:

```
evo-singularity
```

My analyzer settings:

```
{
  "card_database": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "provided_name": "card_database",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "max_result_window": "15000",
        "uuid": "Jfgh8F_FQQO21qSkQDngFw",
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "my_stopwords_filter": {
              "stopwords": [
                "a",
                "an",
                "the"
              ],
              "type": "stop"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "my_stopwords_filter"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "creation_date": "1676906459467",
        "version": {
          "created": "8060199"
        },
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "blocks": {
          "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a link to my mappings:

https://justpaste.it/471fi

Comment: are you some analyzer? can you provide the mapping?

Comment: @rabbitbr Added analyzer settings and link to mapping

Comment: the text "evo-singularity" is indexed in the name field and its mapping does not have any analyzer being used. Already tried to use match query, I simulated and had positive results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TLDR;

It seems like you don't want to be using a `match_phrase` type of query but a `match_phrase_prefix` query.
As in [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html):

> Like the match query but used for matching exact phrases or word proximity matches.

The `extact phrases` makes me think this is not what you want in the case of `evo-sing`.

## Solution

You may switch to a match_phrase_prefix query instead:

```json
GET /75694329/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "name": "evo"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## To reproduce

I use elasticsearch `8.6.2`

Set up:

```json
PUT /75694329/_doc/1
{
  "name": "evo-singularity"
}
```

## Notes

Although you have provided an analyser in your question.
You are not using it on the `name` field, so I used the standard analyzer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this isn't necessarily what I want. When using `match`, fuzziness is applied to the query. What I am trying to achieve is that the user can "disable" fuzzy search on the front-end. What I then want is a query that can do a "partial search" without fuzziness. Currently with your answer, if I type "evo-sing" I get multiple cards returned (including evo-singularity) that are "like" the query. I only want to return "evo-singularity" to match my query of "evo-sing"

Comment: Then maybe you want to try the `match_phrase_prefix` ?

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I needed. I didn't know `match_phrase_prefix` existed! Thank you! If you'd like to edit your answer with that then I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Sure that's done

Answer (score 0):

If the field is indexed as a keyword try to change the query to a term query

Comment: Term can't be used for partial searches. So while I don't want fuzzy matching, I do want to be able to do partial matches "evo-sing" -> "evo-singularity"